# Get only git diff output in tab

Tags: git, vim, vim-fugitive

I want to get only output of `git diff` *of whole repository, not just a file*, in a tab, `Not Split With The Commit Message`!

In the [issues](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/76#issuecomment-1517787) I found a:

```
command GdiffInTab tabedit %|Gdiff
```

But this one opens an split view with commit message, the thing I want is to show only git diff in new tab when editing git commit message.
Is it possible? Or should I try doing it myself, something like:

```
function GitDiffTab()
  exe "tab new %"
  exe "%!git diff"
  exe "se ft=diff"
endfunction
```

But it doesn't work when editing commit message.

Answer (score 3):

Use `:terminal` (requires Vim 8.1+)

```
:-tab terminal git --no-pager diff
```

Using [fugitive.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) we can create a command:

```
command! -bang Tdiff execute '-tab terminal ' . call(fugitive#buffer().repo().git_command, ['--no-pager', 'diff'] + (<bang>0 ? ['--cached'] : []))
```

Use `:Tdiff` to do `git diff` and `:Tdiff!` to do `git diff --cached`

For more help see:

```
:h :tab
:h :terminal
```

Comment: Unfortunately this command didn't work in COMMIT_EDITMSG, just outputs empty tab. However when editing other files of repository it works +1.

Comment: If you are using fugitive for your commits then you can do `:Gcommit -v` or use `cvc` from the `:Gstatus` window to bring up a verbose commit

Comment: Yes that is good solution, but I'd like to see all commit changes in a tab, and another tab for commit message.